# How to disable/stop drag action when using dojo/dnd/Moveable?

Tags: javascript, dojo

I am using a `dojo/dnd/Moveable` in order to drag a `div` on a page, similarly to the example below.

During event `'move'` which run when user is dragging the `div` I need to apply some logic (in my real example I need to check for some mouse coordinate), if logic is not valid I need to STOP dragging the div.

I have tried to use [dojo.dnd.manager.stopDrag()](https://dojotoolkit.org/api/?qs=1.10/dojo/dnd/Manager) with no success.

I would like to know:

- How to **STOP/DISABLE** the drag action?

A sample of working code would be appreciated. Thanks.

https://jsfiddle.net/mbrhb7nn/

```
    require(["dojo/dnd/Moveable", "dojo/dom", "dojo/on", "dojo/domReady!"],
function(Moveable, dom, on){
  on(dom.byId("doIt"), "click", function(){
    var dnd = new Moveable(dom.byId("dndOne"));
              dnd.on('Move', function (event) {
                // add some logic here and stop drag
            }.bind(this));

  });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I was able to solve my problem using `constrainedMoveable` from `dojo/dnd/move`.

Basically it is possible to setup an "area" where the dragging is **only** allowed, I used `constrainedMoveable` as I need to dynamically calculated the "area" .

Actually `dojo/dnd/move` offers severals specialized Movables:

**constrainedMoveable**

used to constrain a move to a dynamically calculated box.

Notes: the function constraints (must be overwritten) and has to return an object with the the following properties for `l,t,w,h` (left/top/width/height).

**boxConstrainedMoveable**

can be used to constrain a move to a predefined box.

**parentConstrainedMoveable**

can be used to constrain the move by the boundaries of the node’s parent.

More information can be [found here](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.10/dojo/dnd.html).

Working example here:
https://jsfiddle.net/mbrhb7nn/5/

```
require(["dojo/dnd/move", "dojo/dom", "dojo/on", "dojo/domReady!"],

function (move, dom, on) {
            var dnd = new move.constrainedMoveable(dom.byId("dndOne"));
            dnd.constraints = function (event) {
                // defines the area where dragging is allowed
                return {
                        l: 0,
                        t: 0,
                        w: 300,
                        h: 300
                    };
            }

});
```

Comment: I would love to see how to actually programmatically STOP the dragging process… Instead of an alternative…